# Node Js Express default limits

Tags: node.js, express

Reading node js doc. They seems to be conservative in the default limit values for http body size and parameters quantity:

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#parameterlimit

I've found you can extend it and this seems to be a proved solution:

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  parameterLimit: 100000,
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
}));
```

However, two  questions remain:

1. Why the default values are so conservative?
2. Why expanding the limit to 50mb is a good idea?

I know the answers depend on the application the solution is applied, but I would appreciate a more general approach oriented answer to understand better the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be the encoding of the HTTP payload.

The Express.js docs (http://expressjs.com/uk/api.html#req.body) say that bodyParser.urlencoded parses x-www-form-urlencoded data.

MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) basically says that x-www-form-urlencoded data is key/value pairs and (I’m reading in between the lines here) not suitable for large amounts of data transmission (use multipart/form-data encoding to send large amounts of data):

> x-www-form-urlencoded: the values are encoded in key-value tuples separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the value. Non-alphanumeric characters are percent encoded: this is the reason why this type is not suitable to use with binary data (use multipart/form-data instead)

bodyParser seems to limit the data as a safety measure to help keep us from running in to transmission errors / issues.  At least, that's how I read it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to think of a legitimate use case where the API would need to accept more than 100 parameters in a single request. Reviewing The Open Web Application Security Project ([OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)) guidelines ([CHEATSHEET HERE](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Denial_of_Service_Cheat_Sheet#2._Request_Size_2)), the default limit values set by ExpressJS seem aligned and responsible. I wouldn't change them.

If you're going down a road where you think these limits may inhibit you from providing the functionality you need, I would strongly consider rethinking your strategy as this will likely open you to unnecessarily security vulnerabilities. For example, you could make multiple smaller requests etc.

Comment: Actually, the 100K limit was my issue, not the parameter part, that code is just copy-paste from another SO answer.